# Slashes and dots in function names and prototypes?

Tags: c, go, notation

I'm new to C and looking at [Go](https://code.google.com/p/go/)'s source tree I found this:

https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/race.c

```
void runtime∕race·Read(int32 goid, void *addr, void *pc);
void runtime∕race·Write(int32 goid, void *addr, void *pc);

void
runtime·raceinit(void)
{
    // ...
}
```

What do the slashes and dots (·) mean? Is this valid C?

Comment: I don't know what they are, but it's not valid (standard) C.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> **IMPORTANT UPDATE:**
>
> [**The ultimate answer** is certainly the one you got **from Russ Cox**](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/MdYlJbW4SAo/TrAEoCjAkMwJ), one of Go authors, on the golang-nuts mailing list. That said, I'm leaving some of my earlier notes below, they might help to understand some things.
>
> Also, from reading this answer linked above, I believe the `∕` "pseudo-slash" may now be translated to regular `/` slash too (like the middot is translated to dot) in newer versions of Go C compiler than the one I've tested below - but I don't have time to verify.

---

The file is compiled by the [Go Language Suite's internal C compiler](http://golang.org/cmd/gc/), which originates in the Plan 9 C compiler<sup>[(1)](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/comp.html)[(2)](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/compiler.html)</sup>, and [has some differences](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/comp.html) (mostly extensions, AFAIK) to the C standard.

One of the extensions is, that it allows UTF-8 characters in identifiers.

Now, in the Go Language Suite's C compiler, the middot character (·) is treated in a special way, as it is translated to a regular dot (.) in object files, which is interpreted by Go Language Suite's internal linker as namespace separator character.

> ### Example
>
> For the following file `example.c` (note: it must be saved as UTF-8 without BOM):
>
> ```
> void ·Bar1() {}
> void foo·bar2() {}
> void foo∕baz·bar3() {}
> ```
>
> the internal C compiler produces the following symbols:
>
> ```
> $ go tool 8c example.c
> $ go tool nm example.8
>  T "".Bar1
>  T foo.bar2
>  T foo∕baz.bar3
> ```
>
> Now, please note I've given the `·Bar1()` a capital `B`. This is
>   because that way, I can make it visible to regular Go code - because
>   it is translated to the exact same symbol as would result from
>   compiling the following Go code:
>
> ```
> package example
> func Bar1() {}  // nm will show:  T "".Bar1
> ```

Now, regarding the functions you named in the question, the story goes further down the rabbit hole. I'm a bit less sure if I'm right here, but I'll try to explain based on what I know. Thus, each sentence below this point should be read as if it had "[AFAIK](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAIK)" written just at the end.

So, the next missing piece needed to better understand this puzzle, is to know something more about the strange `""` namespace, and how the Go suite's linker handles it. The `""` namespace is what we might want to call an "empty" (because `""` for a programmer means "an empty string") namespace, or maybe better, a "placeholder" namespace. And when the linker sees an import going like this:

```
import examp "path/to/package/example"
//...
func main() {
    examp.Bar1()
}
```

then it takes the `$GOPATH/pkg/.../example.a` library file, and during import phase substitutes on the fly each `""` with `path/to/package/example`. So now, in the linked program, we will see a symbol like this:

```
 T path/to/package/example.Bar1
```

Comment: @Tom: by the way, AFAIK you can change the accepted answer on SO if you prefer ;)

Answer (score 8):

The "·" character is `\xB7` according to my Javascript console.
The "∕" character is `\x2215`.

The dot falls within **Annex D** of the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) lists which special characters which are valid as identifiers in C source.  The slash doesn't seem to, so I suspect it's used as something else (perhaps namespacing) via a #define or preprocessor magic.

That would explain why the dot is present in the actual function definition, but the slash is not.

**Edit:** Check [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564148/non-ascii-characters-in-c) for some additional information.  It's possible that the unicode slash is just allowed by GCC's implementation.

Answer (score 5):

It appears this is not standard C, nor C99. In particular, it both `gcc` and `clang` complain about the dot, even when in C99 mode.

This source code is compiled by the Part 9 compiler suite (in particular, ./pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/6c on OS X), which is bootstrapped by the Go build system. According to [this document](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/comp.pdf), bottom of page 8, Plan 9 and its compiler do not use ASCII at all, but use Unicode instead. At bottom of page 9, it it stated that any character with a sufficiently high code point is considered valid for use in an identifier name.

There's no pre-processing magic at all - the definition of functions do not match the declaration of functions simply because those are different functions. For example, `void runtime∕race·Initialize();` is an external function whose definition appears in ./src/pkg/runtime/race/race.go; likewise for `void runtime∕race·MapShadow(…)`.

The function which appears later, `void runtime·raceinit(void)`, is a completely different function, which is aparant by the fact it actually calls `runtime∕race·Initialize();`.

Answer (score 3):

The go compiler/runtime is compiled using the C compilers originally developed for plan9. When you build go from source, it'll first build the plan9 compilers, then use those to build Go.

The plan9 compilers support unicode function names [1], and the Go developers use unicode characters in their function names as pseudo namespaces.

[1] It looks like this might actually be standards compliant: [g++ unicode variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681778/g-unicode-variable-name) but gcc doesn't support unicode function/variable names.