# Go isn't linking my assembly: undefined external function

Tags: assembly, go

I'm trying to write some SIMD mostly for learning purposes. I know Go can link assembly, but I can't get it to work correctly.

Here's the most minimal example I can make (element-wise vector multiplication):

**vec_amd64.s** (note: the actual file has a whitespace line under `RET` since it causes errors otherwise)

```
// func mul(v1, v2 Vec4) Vec4
TEXT .mul(SB),4,$0-48
    MOVUPS v1+0(FP),  X0
    MOVUPS v2+16(FP), X1
    MULPS  X1, X0
    // also tried ret+32 since I've seen some places do that
    MOVUPS X0, toReturn+32(FP)
    RET
```

**vec.go**

```
package simd

type Vec4 [4]float32

func (v1 Vec4) Mul(v2 Vec4) Vec4 {
    return Vec4{v1[0] * v2[0], v1[1] * v2[1], v1[2] * v2[2], v1[3] * v2[3]}
}

func mul(v1, v2 Vec4) Vec4
```

**simd_test.go**

```
package simd

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestMul(t *testing.T) {
    v1 := Vec4{1, 2, 3, 4}
    v2 := Vec4{5, 6, 7, 8}

    res := v1.Mul(v2)
    res2 := mul(v1, v2)

    // Placeholder until I get it to compile
    if res != res2 {
        t.Fatalf("Expected %v; got %v", res, res2)
    }
}
```

When I try to run `go test` I get the error:

```
# testmain
simd.TestMul: call to external function simd.mul
simd.TestMul: undefined: simd.mul
```

The `go env` command reports my `GOHOSTARCH` to be `amd64` and my Go version to be 1.3. To confirm it wasn't the architecture causing the problem, I found another package that uses assembly and deleted all the assembly files except the `_amd64.s` one and its tests ran fine.

I also tried changing it to an exported identifier in case that was causing weirdness, but no dice. I think I pretty closely followed the template in packages like `math/big`, so hopefully it's something simple and obvious that I'm missing.

I know that Go is at least **trying** to use the assembly because if I introduce a syntax error to the .s file the build tool will complain about it.

Edit:

To be clear, `go build` will compile cleanly, but `go test` causes the error to appear.

Comment: `go build` finished cleanly, `go test` fails.

Comment: How do you compile? You didn't answer the question.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question then. I compile using the `go` build tool. If there's an extra step that needs to be in there for assembly that very well may be the answer to my question, but if you're getting at something else I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: What commands did you enter from which directory relative to you source files? *I compile using the `go` build tool.* is very vague. It could mean anything.

Comment: I ran `go test` from `$GOPATH/src/simd`, which is the source directory.

Comment: The Go tool is rather simple and straightforward, I'm not sure what you're getting at. I'm not using advanced flags like coverage profiles or gcflags if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59853/discussion-between-fuzxxl-and-jsor).

Comment: There is a difference between calling `go build` and `go build foo.go`, etc. It might also be possible that you have funky settings in your `$GOPATH`, etc. The more you write about *what exactly* you did, the easier it is to help you. The best thing is to post transcripts of shell sessions instead of prosa.

Comment: Also, the `go` tool is not simple. It exposes all parts of the go build system through various subcommands and options. Any part of the Go building process can be fine-tuned with custom `go` commands.

Comment: The Go language really seems to have a fetish for the mid-dot character. Related: [Slashes and dots in function names and prototypes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475908/slashes-and-dots-in-function-names-and-prototypes)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You are using the wrong dot. instead of

```
TEXT .mul(SB),4,$0-48
```

write

```
TEXT ·mul(SB),4,$0-48
```

and everything works just fine.

Comment: Well THAT was subtle, I did not notice that it was a mid-dot. Thanks.

Comment: It surprises many people. I didn't see it either on first glance.

Comment: How do people type that on an american QWERTY keyboard? Or is this not a common use-case, where you could just google the symbol as necessary?

Comment: [Like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct#Keyboard_input). OSes that don't suck (i.e. not Windows) map unused layers of the QWERTY layout so that characters like the interpunct can be entered.

Comment: @FUZxxl FYI Alt-0183 (using the number-pad) still works for Windows. Not quite as nice, and usually difficult on laptops, but it works.

Comment: On linux (Ubuntu, at least) if you have the [compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) enabled:  `<compose>` `^` `.` = `·`