# how can I link a golang main routine with an assembly written function contained in a separate file?

Tags: go, assembly, linker

I have written a simple go r main routine

```
func main() {

_=add(5,3)
}
```

and an asm file for the add function:

```
text main.add(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-16  
ADDQ BX, AX  
RET
```

How do I link the object files to build an executable? I can compile the go file into an object file and run the assembler to get an object file. The linking returns an error (go tool link) the error is cannot find the runtime.a

The objective is to combine an asm file with a go file to obtain an executable.

Comment: Make sure you use [the right dot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25460967/417501).  That said, could you give your full code and the exact commands you use to assemble and link the code?  The code you have shown is incomplete and won't compile as is.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

### main.go

```
package main

func add(int, int) int

func main() {
    _ = add(5, 3)
}
```

### add.s

```
#include "textflag.h"

TEXT ·add(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-16
    MOVQ    a+0(FP), AX // load first argument
    ADDQ    b+8(FP), AX // add second argument
    RET
```

Place the two files in an empty directory, if building in module-aware mode, create a go.mod file.  Then type `go build` as usual to build.

What's important:

- Read the [assembly documentation](https://golang.org/doc/asm) carefully.  Many things, including the calling convention, are different from what you expect.
- Make sure to [use the right dot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25460967/417501).
- You need to explicitly declare assembly functions in your Go source so the compiler knows how to call it.

Comment: in your implementation of add.s you pull the parameters from the stack. I thought golang moved to pass function parameters via registers.  My version resulted from applying go tool compile -S. Which one is correct? passing function parameters by register or by stack?

Comment: I read your instructions and David Cheneys blog post.  My dir contains 3 files. The first two are copies of what you posted. the go.mod file is:module goTest/assembly/asm

go 1.21.1

Comment: when running go build, i still receive the error:  no function body. So something must have changed with go 1.21

Comment: I created a github repositary: https://github.com/prr123/asmTest

Comment: @prr There is a different ABI for hand-written assembly and for compiler-generated code.  Hand-written assembly uses the stack for parameters. 
 You changing the calling convention could mean that the linker is not able to match up declaration and body.  Read the documentation I linked.

Comment: Also no, they are not copies of what I posted as you have modified the assembly code.

Comment: ok I changed the code to your spec. I still get the same error: function body not found.

Comment: I read the doc. It suggested to look at compiler generated code as guidance. There are many examples of combining stubs with assembly files.

Comment: Did you compile your code? What version of go did you use?

Comment: maybe you could elaborate what you mean by use go build as usual.  This maybe the (my) problem.  I used: go build addMain.go

Comment: @prr That clearly won't work as you failed to list the assembly file.  Just "go build" with no arguments should work.  This builds the package/command in the current working directory.

Comment: thank you for your help. I solved the build issue yesterday by accident.  I added a return value to your code and everything works fine.

Comment: @prr Great!  Make sure to mark an answer as accepted to indicate that your question has been resolved.