# The syntax and semantic of the Go compiler runtime

Tags: c, namespaces, go

I was looking at the runtime.c file in the go runtime at

```
  /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime
```

and saw the following function definitions:

```
   void
   runtime∕pprof·runtime_cyclesPerSecond(int64 res)
   {...}
```

and

```
int64
runtime·tickspersecond(void)
{...}
```

and there are a lot of declarations like

```
void    runtime·hashinit(void);
```

in the runtime.h.

I haven't seen this C syntax before (specially the one with the slash seems odd).
Is this part of std C or some plan9 dialect?

Comment: Too late, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475908/slashes-and-dots-in-function-names-and-prototypes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`∕` and `·` and friends are merely random Unicode characters that someone decided to put in function names. Obscure Unicode characters (**edit:** that are listed in [Annex D of the C99 standard (pages 452-453 of this PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf); see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475908/slashes-and-dots-in-function-names-and-prototypes/)) are just as legal in C identifiers as `A` or `7` (in your average Unicode-capable compiler, anyway).

```
Char|   Hex| Octal|Decimal|Windows Alt-code
----+------+------+-------+----------------
∕   |0x2215|021025|   8725|          (null)
·   |  0xB7|  0267|    183|        Alt+0183
```

Putting characters that look like operators but aren't (U+2215 `∕`, in particular, resembles U+2F `/` (division) far too closely) in function names can be a confusing practice, so I would personally advise against it. Obviously someone on the Go team decided that whatever reasons they had for including them in function names outweighed the potential for confusion.

(**Edit:** It should be noted that U+2215 `∕` isn't expressly permitted by Annex D. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564422/1053021), this may be an extension.)

Comment: @downvoter: Explain? If you informed me of the problem I could repair it.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but not all unicode chars are legal in standard (ANSI) C identifiers. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13476074/532430).

Answer (score 6):

It's Go's special internal syntax for Go package paths. For example,

`runtime∕pprof·runtime_cyclesPerSecond`

is function `runtime_cyclesPerSecond` in package path `runtime∕pprof`.

The '`∕`' character is the Unicode division slash character, which separates path elements. The '`·`' character is the Unicode middle dot character, which separates the package path and the function.